# Set legend in sympy plot implicit

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I having issues with setting a legend to a basic plot using simply plot implicit. I am receiving next issue: No handles with labels found to put in legend.
Would help me with this?
Best

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x,y,z

def z(x, y):
    return x - y

sp.plot_implicit(z(x, y), (x,0,3),(y,0,3), show=True, legend=True, label='Test')
```

Comment: Doesn't work till now